# Cannot use an abstract class Angular component in a module declaration

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a base component class `BaseComponent` with its own markup, let's say this component is `<base-component-fun>`. Its markup is:

```
<div>
..Base markup
</div>
```

I export this component via module and reuse the library in other project when I inherit this component - and have its own markup + base component markup:

```
import { BaseComponent } from 'my-repository/base';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class InheritedComponent extends BaseComponent
```

with the markup:

```
<inherited-component-fun>
  ..Inherited markup
  <base-component-fun></base-component-fun>
</inherited-component-fun>
```

Here comes the problem: I MUST declare my base class `BaseComponent` in its module for export:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [BaseComponent],
```

otherwise the module is not built. But declaring an abstract class is not allowed.

What do I do? I've tried to find the solution in forums, but I could not. So I ended up by making base class non-abstract, which is not very good from design prospective - I want to have some abstract properties ih the base class.

Comment: how do you plan to render abstract BaseComponent here `<base-component-fun>` ? obviously it complains

Comment: Component inheritence just inherits the methods, you need to supply complete template each time. You cannot include partial template of `abstract class`.

Comment: @andrei - well, from this prospective it makes sense... but what if I need to have some abstract properties which make no sense in the base class, but need to be implemented in the inherited class? Neither abstract class, no interface work nice here...

Comment: @prajwal - in my case, i needed to use both code inheritance and kind of markup 'inheritance'.. This is why i came up with such solution. Inheritance was the best approach there - not injecting the child markup.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I see you are trying to render something like this.

```
component specific template
...
base class/component template
...
component specific template
```

This doesn't work with the way you are trying to do. You cannot render a class without declaring it in the module and you cannot declare an abstract one.

Possible solutions,

**1. Use Content Projection** - https://angular.io/guide/content-projection

Make the base class as parent and use the content projection to fill the required sections. You can put the child components here

**2. Use complete template**

If it is a simple structural change (may be like adding a `card` class etc), I would suggest you to just use the complete template again.

**3. Use both abstract class and content projection**

Use abstract class for the child component, and use a parent component with content projection to get the proper template.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think #3 is most likely what I need. Actully my current solution with NOT abstract class does work, however probably I'd like to improve it. My base class is AddressComponent. And the inherited class is a class where AddressComponent markup is a SUBFORM (FormGroup) of the inherited class form, with half hundred of form fields, form field events and other complex things. This is the reason I decided to use inheritance - to easily jump in into event workflow, change detection, etc... I now think if I will be able to use ng-content to build SUBFORM...

Comment: @Alexander you are welcome. You can select the component (used within ng-content) using `viewChild` and from that object you can call relevant methods. May be you should also check it out.